# Git since timestamp

Tags: git

When I run the command:

```
git log --after=21/9/2012
```

It seems to have a hidden timestamp set to the current time. By that I mean, if I run the command at 10am, it will only show me commits from 10am on the 21st. I've looked at the documentation and a few websites but can't find a way to specify the time as well as the date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the time after the date. For instance

```
git log --after="2012-09-22 00:00:00"
```